# How to select a single OneLineListItem in MDlist in kivymd

Tags: python, windows, kivymd

I am trying to select a OneLineListItem in my MDlist so that I can interact with it. Currently the default behavior when clicking an item in the list is for it to turn grey for a second and then fade away. I would like the OneLineListItem widget to stay highlighted and to be able to reference the selected item so that I can interact with it. I looked at MDSelectionList but I don't want to have to do a long press and only want to be able to select one item in the list at a time.

Clicking on it and for it to stay selected.